# cannot get xml element value in visual basic

Tags: xml, vb.net

i cannot select elements in visual basic because xml file is really complex. i am tring to select everything under item.

visual basic file:

```vb
       Dim node As XmlNode
        Dim nodelist As XmlNodeList
        Dim nsmgr As XmlNamespaceManager
        Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
        
    xmlDoc.Load("C:\Users\turin\Downloads\contactpersonen.xml")

    ' Namespace manager aanmaken
    nsmgr = New XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable)
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("SOAP-ENV", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")

    ' selecteren van xml element
    nodelist = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//SOAP-ENV:Body/ds_rl_contactpersonen_result/fields/item/rl_contactpersonen_relateregistratienr", nsmgr)

    Convert.ToString(nodelist)
    Console.WriteLine(nodelist)`
```

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body
        xmlns:SOAP-SEC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/security/2000-12" SOAP-SEC:id="Body">
        <ds_rl_contactpersonen_result
            xmlns="urn:EfDataService">
            <fields  xsi:type="ds_rl_contactpersonen_fieldsArray">
                <item id="bk101" xsi:type="ds_rl_contactpersonen_fields">
                    <rl_contactpersonen_relatieregistratienr xsi:type="xsd:int">2996657</rl_contactpersonen_relatieregistratienr>
                    <rl_contactpersonen_contactvolgnr xsi:type="xsd:int">1</rl_contactpersonen_contactvolgnr>
                    <rl_contactpersonen_contactpersoonsnr xsi:type="xsd:int">6149365</rl_contactpersonen_contactpersoonsnr>
                    <rl_contactpersonen_status xsi:type="xsd:int">26880</rl_contactpersonen_status>
```

it just returns in console:

System.Xml.XPathNodeList

Answer (score 0):

SelectNodes return a XmlNodeList, not a single node. So you must initialize nodelist with the parent element 'item' and  enumerate it to get child nodes :

```
    nodelist = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//SOAP-ENV:Body/ds_rl_contactpersonen_result/fields/item", nsmgr)
    
    for each childNode as XmlNode in nodeList 'enumerate childs
     
     'print some interesting properties
     Console.WriteLine childNode.Name
     Console.WriteLine childNode.innerXml
     Console.WriteLine childNode.innerText
    
    'get particular child
     if chilNode.Name="rl_contactpersonen_relatieregistratienr" then 
      {----your stuff----}
     endif

    next
```

you can also get node directly with SelectSingleNode :

```
    dim childNode as XmlNode =  xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//SOAP-ENV:Body/ds_rl_contactpersonen_result/fields/item/rl_contactpersonen_relateregistratienr", nsmgr)
   'childNode.innerText will return '2996657'
```